# Force Perl to stop special processing of command line arguments if -e eval switch is used

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments

```sh
perl -e 'print(123, @ARGV);' a b
# 123ab

perl -e 'print(123, @ARGV);' --help
# prints Perl's help instead
```

This is a toy example demonstrating the problem. In my real use-case I'm using `-e` to execute a large script from an embedded interpreter using `perl_parse(...)` function, the script has its own processing of `--help` switch, so I'd like to block any special processing of command line arguments after `-e`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a double hyphen to stop argument processing:

```
$ perl -e'print "[@ARGV]\n"' -- --help
[--help]
$
```

Comment: Same to end `-s` and Getopt::Long processing. `perl -se'print "[$opt1|$opt2|@ARGV]"' -- -opt1=abc -- -opt2=def` outputs `[abc||-opt2=def]`

Comment: The `--` to indicate the end of the command line arguments also works in many other Posix programs, see guideline 10 in the [Posix interface guidelines](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02)

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work even for `perl_parse(...)`!